# Scrolling on Android Mobile not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make my site responsive.But no matter how much I scroll it still keeps me on the same div element.I am using a plugin called jquery-momentum-scroll.js and a plugin called vide.js.The wrapper covering the whole is given below-

```
#main {
    height: inherit;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: transform 1.2s ease-out;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}`
```

The element that is showing no matter how much I scroll is given below-

```
#banner_wrapper {
    margin-top: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I have tried removing the "position: fixed;" property but still that did not do the trick.But when I resize the browser it shows fine.The link of the site is given below-

https://robustious-methods.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `#main` section is taking over the view-port no matter where you scroll, is because you are using `position: fixed;` for the element's positioning.

With `position: fixed`, this takes the element out of the flow of the document, and fixes it relative to the screen. In this case, you've set it to take up 100% of the width and using `top: 0; bottom: 0;` in your styling, you're telling it to take up 100% of the height also.

If you want to keep the element in the flow of the document, change `position: fixed` to `position: relative;` on the `#main` selector, or remove it completely.

If you'd like to maintain the full height banner, in the `#banner_wrapper` selector, remove `height: 900px;` and add `height: 100vh;`.

More reading about CSS positioning [here](http://learnlayout.com/position.html).

Comment: Changing the position from fixed to relative or not giving positions crashes my plugin and css both.I have already mentioned it before